# Multiple value checks with if condition python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

How to excecute mutiple value with `if` condition like below, i tried it but not working

```
if 'mydj-lb-foxdc01' or 'tsdj-lb-foxdc02' or 'mydj-lb-noivm01' or 'mydj-lb-noivm02' not in line:
```

Below is working while tried ..

```
if 'mydj-lb-foxdc01' not in line:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any()` builtin method:

```
line = 'mydj-lb-noivm01'

if not any(['mydj-lb-foxdc01' in line, 'tsdj-lb-foxdc02' in line, 'mydj-lb-noivm01' in line, 'mydj-lb-noivm02' in line]):
    print('not in line')
else:
    print('in line')
```

Output:

```
in line
```

Comment: Thnx Andrej .. checking this.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = 'mydj-lb-noivm01'

if not any(['mydj-lb-foxdc01' in line, 'tsdj-lb-foxdc02' in line, 'mydj-lb-noivm01' in line, 'mydj-lb-noivm02' in line]):
    print('not in line')
else:
    print('in line')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful; please add some words explaining/describing why your suggested code answers the question.